# How to commit project updations?

Tags: git, github, git-svn, bitbucket

I am using the following command to load the updated contents on my project (I already have a repository and my source code on bitbucket), however I am unable to see any commits on my bitbucket account and even the modifications I made to the code are not appearing in the bitbucket repository...

```
 $ cd /path/to/my/repo
 $ git remote add origin https://abc@bitbucket.org/abc/test.git
 $ git push -u origin master
```

Can some guide how should I go about..I have my repository and my initial source code is already on bitbucket, I just want to commit the updations I made to the code to bitbucket...I am clueless as to how should I go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you did was register the remote. Nothing come down from the remote location yet. Pushing is something you do to make your changes go across to the remote, not the other way around.

**Short answer:** `git clone` instead.

**Long answer:**

You need to fetch first.

```
git fetch origin
```

will get the remote references and all objects referenced therein.

```
git branch -r
```

will list the branches that you pulled down (such as origin/master).

To update your master (assuming you already have it checked out)

```
git merge --ff-only origin/master
```

although just

```
git pull master
```

will work for you in this case.

Other branches can be made locally from the remote and checked out with

```
git checkout origin/some-feature
```

Comment: I have cloned my test project using `git clone https://abc@bitbucket.org/abc/test.git`  I am not getting what to do with the clone. Thanks a lot for helping..really appreciate u r help

Comment: the syntax is `git clone some-url some-dir`. You can then cd into that dir and you should have the whole repo there.

Comment: True I have the repository in the folder specified....but my problem is how do I make the updations to the huge code (consisting of several files)...shall I merge them with the clone downloaded code...I mean how to I make my changes apparent to my teammates after cloning and having the repo. Sorry for my ignorance and thanks for replying...hoping that you'll be kind to help this time too. Now after merging my folder with the cloned folder when I am `git push -u origin master:master' I am  still getting "everything: up-to-date". Please help out I am new to bitbucket and I am really stuck

Comment: no need to merge. Once you clone, master should be at the latest. Just overwrite the working directory by copying your work into the cloned version. Now `git add -A` to stage all the changes. Now `git commit -m "some message"` to commit them. Now publish them to the remote so others can see your work or you have a backup if you're working alone with `git push origin master`